# Automapper mapping element with subelement that is list to the same Destination

Tags: automapper

I have the following structure (simplified):

```
class Source {
    string test {get; set;}
    List<SubClass> items {get; set;}
}

class SubClass {
    string rating {get; set;}
    string otherrating {get; set;}
}

class Destination {
    string test {get; set;}
    sttring rating {get; set;}
    string otherrating {get; set;}
}
```

I need to use Automapper like this:

```
Source -> Destination (this will affect "test" property)

Source.Items[0] -> `Desination` (this will affect "rating" && "otherrating" property)
```

I would like to do this using automapper, because I have more fields than in above example

Can you give me suggestions? I am able to create map just for `Source` (without `SubClass`).

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ReverseMap();
...
var src = GetSourceWithListsFromDB(); // returns object of class Source
...
var model = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(src); // this maps Source, but doesn't map Source.Items[0].rating
```

I have tried the following mapping:

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src => src.items[0]))
```

but this throws error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the mapping for both rating and otherrating fields

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.rating, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.items[0].rating))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.otherrating, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.items[0].otherrating));
Mapper.CreateMap<Destination, Source>()
            .ForMember(dest =>dest.items, opt => opt.MapFrom(s=> new List<SubClass> {new SubClass(){ rating = s.rating, otherrating = s.otherrating}}));
```

Comment: Is this the only way? Because actually I have many properties not only those two.

Comment: @renathy You can also create a custom converter see [here]http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters 
but you will also have to write some code.